# Keep indentation after directive in list

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In RST for a sphinx documentation and using the `sphinx.ext.imgmath` extension for maths equations, I would like to add an equation in the middle of a bullet point list but have a second paragraph after the said equation and keep the indentation level of the bullet point. I think the problem would be the same with any other kind of directive than `math`.

My current RST code looks like this:

```
Introducing the bullet list on zero-th level indentation:

- First bullet point on first level indentation.

.. math::

   centered math equation

I would like this to be at the first level indentation because it belongs to the first bullet point but it lands on zero-th level indentation.

- Second bullet point on first level indentation.
```

And this gives:

```
Introducing the bullet list on zero-th level indentation:
    
    - First bullet point on first level indentation.
    
                     centered math equation
    
I would like this to be at the first level indentation because it belongs to the first bullet point but it lands on zero-th level indentation.
    
    - Second bullet point on first level indentation.
```

but I would like:

```
Introducing the bullet list on zero-th level indentation:
    
    - First bullet point on first level indentation.
    
                     centered math equation
    
      I would like this to be at the first level indentation because it belongs to the first bullet point but it lands on zero-th level indentation.
    
    - Second bullet point on first level indentation.
```

Comment: Then indent `I would like...` so it aligns with `First bullet point...`. You should also indent `.. math::` as it should be part of the first bullet point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent the `math` block and the paragraph after it.

```text
Introducing the bullet list on zero-th level indentation:

- First bullet point on first level indentation.

  .. math::

     centered math equation

  I would like this to be at the first level indentation because it belongs to the first bullet point  but it lands on zero-th level indentation.

- Second bullet point on first level indentation.
```

Consistent indentation is very important. See https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#indentation.

Comment: There is a really strange behavior happening here. When I do what you propose, I get the "I would like " paragraph indented at... the second indentation level, so there is a little offset to the right compared to the indentation level of the "First bullet point" and "Second bullet point " paragraphs. This doesn't look good. **BUT** if I do what you propose and I add a tab between the dash `-` and "First" so that, in the source: "First" is at the same horizontal level than "I would like" and ".. math::", but the dash stays at the left most end of the line. Then I get the desired output.

Comment: To understand my previous comment, it must be noted that my tab character is equal to 4 spaces.

Comment: I don't use tabs at all. I have only spaces.